# Unable to left join within a SQL query containing CTEs

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I need to combine the results from two different CTEs into a single table. Hence, I have written the following SQL query wherein I attempted to create a left join on two different fields (patient_id, quarter in example below).

Unfortunately, I am getting a SQL compilation error (Unknown user defined function A.YR_QTR). *But I have declared this variable in the code so am at a loss to why this error is cropping up.* My code follows below:

```
WITH op_clms AS 
(
    SELECT 
        MC.UNIV_MBR_ID AS univ_mbr_id, 
        MC.YR_QTR AS YR_QTR,
        COUNT DISTINCT MC.ENC_KEY AS op_clms
    FROM 
        CRF.MED_CLAIMS AS MC 
    WHERE 
        MC.SERVICE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
        AND PLACE_OF_SERVICE ! = '23'
),
ed_clms AS 
(
    SELECT 
        MC.UNIV_MBR_ID AS univ_mbr_id, 
        MC.YR_QTR AS YR_QTR,
        COUNT DISTINCT MC.ENC_KEY AS ed_clms
    FROM 
        CRF.MED_CLAIMS AS MC 
    WHERE 
        MC.SERVICE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
        AND PLACE_OF_SERVICE  = '23'
)
SELECT 
    a.UNIV_MBR_ID, a.YR_QTR
    (IFNULL(op_clms, 0)) AS op_clms, 
    (IFNULL(ed_clms,0)) AS ed_clms,
    1 as cohort
FROM 
    (SELECT UNIV_MBR_ID, YR_QTR 
     FROM op_clms
     UNION
     SELECT UNIV_MBR_ID, YR_QTR 
     FROM ed_clms) a
LEFT JOIN 
    op_clms ON a.UNIV_MBR_ID = op_clms.UNIV_MBR_ID 
            AND a.YR_QTR = op_clms.YR_QTR
LEFT JOIN 
    ed_clms ON a.UNIV_MBR_ID = ed_clms.UNIV_MBR_ID
            AND a.YR_QTR = ed_clms.YR_QTR
```

Can somebody please guide me on what I am doing wrong? Each of the individual CTEs check out fine on their own. And I cant find anything else syntactically/logically wrong with my code.

Comment: Tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. I'm guessing MySQL due to the `IFNULL`, but nobody should be required to guess.

Comment: Added. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Yes, each of the CTE codes (op_clms, ed_clms) execute just fine.

Comment: Perusing the `FROM` syntax of Snowflake makes me think it doesn't support subqueries in a `FROM`, at least not for join purposes. Try making your `UNION` a CTE of its own, then joining on that.

Comment: It seems I forgot to add a comma after the YR_QTR towards the end of the query! Adding that fixes the issue I was having! Thank you so much for brainstorming through your queries here Jeroen

Comment: ...or a typo, yes. The number of times I've omitted a comma and ended up with a query that ran, but produced incorrect results (with a column being inadvertently aliased) can't be counted on the fingers of two hands (in decimal, at least).

Comment: So snowflake actually allows something like `COUNT DISTINCT MC.ENC_KEY`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears in my original code, I inadvertently omitted a comma after a.YR_QTR. Adding that as shown below, fixes the issue!

```
    a.UNIV_MBR_ID, a.YR_QTR,
    (IFNULL(op_clms, 0)) AS op_clms, 
    (IFNULL(ed_clms,0)) AS ed_clms,
    1 as cohort
```

Comment: And to answer question above from LukStorms, snowflake did allow the COUNT DISTINCT <column_name> operation just fine